# Qual seria a tradução correta para "won" e "earned" nessa ilustração?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, significado-em-contexto

Na figura baixo temos: "where gold medals are won" e "where gold medals are earned". Estou meio confuso em relação ao "won" e "earned". Qual seria a tradução mais adequada no contexto da figura abaixo para que faça sentido a imagem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um meme (de qualidade [questionável](https://www.reddit.com/r/im14andthisisdeep/comments/8967tn/i_dont_even_know_what_this_is_supposed_to_mean/)) criado a partir da ilustração [*Expand your comfort zone*](http://www.davidebonazzi.com/uploads/1/7/8/2/17822545/comfort-1-web_orig.jpg) ("Expanda sua zona de conforto") de [Davide Bonazzi](http://www.davidebonazzi.com/portfolio.html). O autor do meme, portanto, provavelmente quer afirmar que é preciso sair de sua zona de conforto para vencer.

Tanto *win* quanto *earn* podem geralmente ser traduzidas como "ganhar", o que obviamente não funcionaria aqui. Para enfatizar o sentido de merecimento de *earn* uma possibilidade seria "conquistar". Com isso as frases ficariam:

- Onde medalhas de ouro são ganhas.
- Onde medalhas de ouro são conquistadas.